# Azure CORS Variable Allowed Origins

Tags: azure, cors, azure-resource-manager

Whenever a new release pipeline is ran in Azure DevOps, the URL Is changed.. currently my ARM template has a hard-coded URL which can be annoying to keep on adding in manually.

```
"cors": {
      "allowedOrigins": [
        "[concat('https://',parameters('storage_account_name'),'.z10.web.core.windows.net')]"
    }
```

The only thing that changes is the `10` part in the `z10` so essentially i want it to be something like
`[concat('https://',parameters('storage_account_name'),'.z', '*', '.web.core.windows.net')]` I dont know if something like that is valid but essentially its so that the cors policy will accept the URL regardless of the z number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically speaking this is not possible, because of the CORS standard ([see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)).
which allows only for exact origins, wildcard, or null.

For instance, ARM for Azure Storage is also following this pattern allowing you to put a list of exact origins or a wildcard ([see ARM docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.storage/2018-07-01/storageaccounts/blobservices))

However, if you know your **website** name, in your ARM you can receive the full host and use it in your CORS:

```
"[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('SiteName')), '2018-02-01').defaultHostName]"
```

The same with a **static website** (which is your case I guess) if you know the storage account name:

```
"[reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01', 'Full').properties.primaryEndpoints.web]"
```

## Advance reference output manipulation

Answering on comment - if you would like to replace some characters in the output from the `reference` function the easiest way is to use build-in replace function ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string?tabs=json#examples-17))

In case you need a more advanced scenario I am pasting my solution by introducing a custom function which is removing `https://` and `/` from the end so `https://contonso.com/` is transformed to `contonso.com`:

```
"functions": [
   {
      "namespace": "lmc",
      "members": {
         "replaceUri": {
            "parameters": [
                {
                   "name": "uriString",
                   "type": "string"
                }
             ],
             "output": {
                "type": "string",
                "value": "[replace(replace(parameters('uriString'), 'https://',''), '/','')]"
             }
         }
      }
  }
],

# ...(some code)...

"resources": [
# ... (some resource)...:
      "properties": {
         "hostName": "[lmc.replaceUri(reference(variables('storageNameCdn')).primaryEndpoints.blob)]"
       }
]
```

Comment: Just one thing i noticed.. for the static website its adding a "/" at the end of the CORS polic which is breaking it..is there a way to remove that trailing /

Comment: I added an example of how to create your own function to manipulate output. However try to use the build-in replace method at the beginning: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-string?tabs=json#examples-17